# How to verify that parent process has exited in golang on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, go, synchronization

So I am writing a small utility which should be able to update itself (replace it's own binary).

The best way to do this on Windows seems to be:

1. Download the new version of the binary as my.exe.new
2. my.exes runs my.exe.new and exits
3. my.exe.new waits  for my.exe to exit
4. my.exe.new copies itself as my.exe
5. my.exe.new starts another copy of itself as my.exe and exits
6. my.exe waits for my.exe.new to exit
7. my.exe removes my.exe.new

Now for all of this to work I have to be able to synchronize the state between the processes (being able to know when the parent has exited), but it seems that os.Getppid (nor syscall.Getppid) in golang Windows is not implemented as it always returns -1.

I've seen that patches are underway, but I am not willing to patch my standard libraries.

Is there an easy way to make Getppid working on even older versions of Go (perhaps reimplementing it?), or perhaps anyone can suggest a better method of synchronizing between the process state?

The thing which comes to mind is binding on a socket, but thats a big hacky.

Perhaps passing a pipe to the child process, and the child waiting for the pipe to close?

Thanks

Comment: [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) the parent process with process access right [`SYNCHRONIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880.aspx), and [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) on the returned handle. The handle will become signaled when the process terminates.

Comment: You could try to do a `syscall.Exec()` to replace the current process by the new program image you just downloaded. You could implement an extra command line flag that causes your program to look for a temporary download and discard it.

Comment: But how to I OpenProcess if I don't have the parent pid?

Comment: Exec would not unlock the binary though?

Comment: @Jammer I'm actually not sure. It should unlock the old binary but the new one will become locked in the process. You could call exec() twice—once from the old binary and then from a temporary binary that moves the new binary in place and exec()'s it.

Comment: @FUZxxl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/431x4c1w.aspx

Comment: You can pass the parent PID as a command-line parameter to the child process.

Comment: if getting the PID is the problem, use pkg os/exec command with windows "tasklist.exe", parse the outcome for the pid of my.exe and use that for killing the different my.exe versions.

Comment: @arx actually that has inspired me to pass the PID as an env var. Can you post your answer, I guess you should post your answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: @FUZxxl when I try syscall.Exec on Windows I get an error: _not supported by windows_

Comment: @Jammer Huch? That's funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent process can pass its PID to the child.

You could use a command-line parameter or an environment variable to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `os.Stdin` with `exec.Cmd`, now I don't have access to windows to test this, however the same concept should apply there just fine:

```
var child = flag.Bool("child", false, "damn children and their music")

func init() {
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    if *child {
        fmt.Println("child start", time.Now())

        // wait until the parent dies and bufio closes the stdin
        ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Println("the parent is dead", time.Now())
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("tada\n")

    } else {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, time.Now())
        cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "-child")
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout //not needed in a real program.

        //this is important, bufio will close after the parent exits, 
        // unlike os.Stdin which screws up, at least on linux
        cmd.Stdin = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin) 

        fmt.Println("giving painful birth:", cmd.Start())
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am already passing the descriptors to the children to preserve logging redirections.

Comment: Using stdin won't work right anyway since the process will won't be the "active" process anymore even after the parent dies, you will have to use file logging or system logging.

Comment: That's not true. See [this](http://play.golang.org/p/rpg10gn2TS), though you have to run it locally.